# Keep track of argument types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, builder

I have a Builder pattern implemented in TypeScript for some of my entities. Here is one of them (stripped for simplicity) and also [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQ0lAvFBA7EBuAUKZGAGwEsATaNTHfcaAQQxIFsFgSB7DVdLPXCAA8wHAE7AoAYyIIAzrNikKAIQCuJIhVFQA3rlxQoYUSQBubaLKUQAXIvIR+hsKoBGpSVFnA2JT94RxAAoASl0oUQhgVVFuDAgAd3sVdU0IUVDsKABffWc3DygEkmA4eCQIIIwEZlsvYBMMAHMAGi9ESDtyyBC7UpIFPUNDftkAOisHMYQyMm7K6tq22Q6IELxhiKiY7lGNnLyjAr8ikrhGFl8uKpq670bW3kv2LjsL1heMXqhR3QNh0YTazTWbvK4YG5LJ4fThffaGSLRWI-OADfa5f4udwnYqlADyoi0QRWFTs9xIzTamGesNkZIaFKaAG0ALphIYA1HjSYUEFkAlEkmQKlMGFcWTrf4I7bIvb-XIY4gONQaLT-CY+YIhdW4sqrIIAIgAEhAiEQOFAAOpiTQGto6bLawxjXVgz6Gt2wgCMdt0jp1Z091wNQYwACZfQ6nVAXWcBelDQBhDiqTRQVzQADkJrNFutok0magXCIIF9TINydTZHTWdDXqLYigmdDYcbGFLBrZQA):

```
type Shape = any;
type Slide = any;
type Animation = any;

export class SlideBuilder {

  private slide: Slide;

  public static start() { return new SlideBuilder(); }

  public withShape(name: string, shape: Shape): this {
    this.slide.addShape(name, shape);
    return this;
  }

  public withAnimation(name: string, animation: Animation): this {
    this.slide.addAnimation(name, animation);
    return this;
  }

  public withOrder(shape: string, animations: string[]) {
    this.slide.addOrder(shape, animations);
    return this;
  }
}

SlideBuilder
  .start()
  .withShape("Hello World", {})
  .withAnimation("Animation1", {})
  .withAnimation("Animation2", {})
  .withOrder("Could be 'Hello World' only", ["Could be 'Animation1' or 'Animation2' only"])
```

The thing is, I want to add a possibility to type check that `withOrder` has been called with the right parameters, parameters that have been already passed to `withShape` or `withAnimation`.

I've already tried adding generic types to the class, like:

```
export class SlideBuilder<S, A> {
  withShape(name: S, shape: Shape)
  withAnimation(name: A, animation: Animation)
  withOrder(shape: S, animation: A[])
}
```

But I couldn't find a way to keep track each call, like collecting each type from the call into union type. I understand that I need to specify somehow `withOrder(shape: S1 | S2 | S3 | ... | Sn)` where `Sn` is a type from `withShape` call, but how actually implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a wonderful question that was enjoyable to answer!

*How do we make the compiler track all of the arguments that a class instance's methods have received over the life of the instance?*

Whew! That is a big ask! I was not sure at first whether it was possible.

Here is what the compiler must do over the lifetime of the class instance:

- On each method call, add to the set of arguments that the instance has received.
- Group those arguments, so that we can type check with them later.

Here we go...

## Answer

The following approach is complicated enough that I have provided only the method signatures. I have also simplified those signatures to the minimum requirements that can express the idea. The method implementations will be relatively straight forward for you to provide.

The approach uses accumulator types to keep track of the argument types. These accumulator types are similar to the accumulator objects that we would use in an `Array.reduce` function.

Here is [the playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwMYGsDKALBkDOAeGNAGwEsATCAIQFcSiK4AaWAOQgA9hNsIA%20KALxQAUFFjFyVWvQhwoHYBAB2ZHFAkUadBnhJKAZrPFZczPYbkwAgkpIBbBMBIB7JTn6ioAfnWlN0nUITCDUAH1YFbkhma1sHJ1d3ETEALiglCAA3WQBuYWFQSFhEVBt7Rxc3Ag0pbVkYtk4y%20Mr%20IU9CP1qZOQVlVV9JLR7dAyMgnhwzMctmisSPMR8a4cCokJi5hLcocJhG4C3W5Kg0jOy4POEOMGc4YCgkIgQcNRWA2Wrgzbj5pX4AN75MRgagAI1ISCgOGAFShMIQ9wAFABKNLvOpwPDnerpLKyQGeMRwCDAahwJR4gDug38mOx%20KYeIuvFReTEAF8riDwZCoFSSMAMOsCAd5Jx%20moYXA9ABzVlKBB2CBpfYKNHFZDoYL4IUkKYRTiEsQmqBCuDOGkZGkAUTgFrgSIA5DAAPIAEVdUAAknYwEQIMqlA8BUL1gA6J0o9lQDnAqCgiEkKGhjBHVyihTixQqKXAGVKeVIxXK1UHDXwLXpqp6g1qo1QIGmsTmy3UqB2h3Ot2en1%20gNBkOCtO-baR6OeOOeRN81OuuAMJE4YKq9bMBCjyqq6sAbQAuhra42iWaMBarRBbfa7t2PV7ff7A8oh0L5wxxzG41OAPTfqAABReHAQjNcBoCQDAIFQOVw2EDEek8cMEWRFFENTdYkQAInWABGTDULEcNU2rZ1qxwqM0OHN9ZCw3DMOYHdMLIzCD3yX8AKAkDCnAyDoMLWD4IYRDkOAVFKLDYJaOCPCCKgIjhxIp0yIowjiM3VxSPUpQACYVLkucFxo7DpPoqBGOY5gmK07SWNQ4R2IAMQQOg1G4x5eJQGC4K6VZZGE2EUPE4VJOMngZKCxTlNk%20ShUi6y9JijBqMdTCHOcZxTPMrS8Ms6sbNY%20y-yclzQKKCCoM8-jvKGD44H8xFROi9CQropqFK0zTym2ci2tijqlPi3qksMlK6IY1L0tMqyusqfKUSAA) and the code:

```
type TrackShapes<TSlideBuilder, TNextShape> = 
  TSlideBuilder extends SlideBuilder<infer TShapes, infer TAnimations> 
  ? SlideBuilder<TShapes | TNextShape, TAnimations> 
  : never;

type TrackAnimations<TSlideBuilder, TNextAnimation> = 
  TSlideBuilder extends SlideBuilder<infer TShapes, infer TAnimations> 
  ? SlideBuilder<TShapes, TAnimations | TNextAnimation> 
  : never;

export class SlideBuilder<TShape, TAnimation> {

  public static start(): SlideBuilder<never, never> {
    return new SlideBuilder<never, never>();
  };

  public withShape<TNext extends string>(name: TNext): TrackShapes<this, TNext> {
      throw new Error('TODO Implement withShape.');
  }

  public withAnimation<TNext extends string>(name: TNext): TrackAnimations<this, TNext> {
      throw new Error('TODO Implement withAnimation.');
  }

  public withOrder(shape: TShape, animation: TAnimation[]): this {
    throw new Error('TODO Implement withOrder.');
  }
}
```

## What is going on there?

We define two accumulator types for the `SlideBuilder`. These receive an existing `SlideBuilder`, `infer` its shape and animation types, use a type union to widen the appropriate generic type, and then return the `SlideBuilder`. This is the most advanced part of the answer.

Then inside `start`, we use `never` to initialize the `SlideBuilder` at zero (so to speak). This is useful because the union of `T | never` is `T` (similarly to how `5 + 0 = 5`).

Now each call to `withShape` and `withAnimation` uses the appropriate accumulator as its return type. That means that each call widens the type appropriately and categorizes the argument in the appropriate bucket!

Note that the `withShape` and `withAnimation` generics `extend string`. This constrains the type to `string`. It also prevents widening the string literal type to `string`. That means callers do not need to use `as const` and thus provides a friendlier API.

The result? We "keep track of" argument types! Here are some tests that show how it meets the requirements.

## Test Cases

```
// Passes type checking.
SlideBuilder
  .start()
  .withShape("Shape1")
  .withAnimation('Animation1')
  .withOrder("Shape1", ["Animation1"])

// Passes type checking.
SlideBuilder
  .start()
  .withShape("Shape1")
  .withAnimation('Animation1')
  .withAnimation('Animation2')
  .withOrder("Shape1", ["Animation1", "Animation2"])

// Fails type checking.
SlideBuilder
  .start()
  .withShape("Shape1")
  .withAnimation('Animation1')
  .withAnimation('Animation2')
  .withOrder("Foo", ["Animation1", "Animation2"])

// Fails type checking.
SlideBuilder
  .start()
  .withShape("Shape1")
  .withAnimation('Animation1')
  .withAnimation('Animation2')
  .withOrder("Shape1", ["Foo", "Animation2"])
```

## Evolution of the Answer

Finally, here are some playground links that show the evolution of this answer:

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUgRBTAZgSwHb0gQ1VgxrgVwFsCAbTAFwHsAnSRWyCgCwwGVTkATeAIQOSkeNAHRQQwcBQCeABwwBBfMTKVaAHgAqHbnwFD4NADSRNAOXgAPCm2aZ5APkgBeSFFM6e-QcMhWK8KhcAM6Qnno+hupoiIaQSoQk5NQ0Tu4A-GGcXvrC6gkqyYwAPqYW1rb28GmQkABckOgAboYA3ODgVrK0FJC45MGh4d4GNFqVjpAA3u6gELXQYRSYNL0A7sgsWFm6I74slJB2oQDkzYYnWKGboTLyIm4LMJrMyNehnADWGMHLq2gAcyYrDwiVUKSwvQAXoYqGInpJarICAAjTi4SC-SjIDFY1YACgAlA1hrkoudUtN3LUaPAKAQaDh0GsdjlImMKQ4ie1agBfdqzMDUmAAUUwuGYTGQRAwawwmC4XG2wTs8hMCqVLAwdwwVEQwMOKqqTCowPlyiSalEwsRkGRaJxkA2LAm8C05Rsquq+NQmBlDXM-ldxPiFvBGhYbxMgYqXqcMwWCxYNCoLOZkBFNBTNHxJ00AHlYPnIABJIiyUjwGWodabZiukQnQk8yC8jq1ObCyAAYSoqF+NEwaCddfzNH2pvFuHgsl6fdI0iwOBWg8Xeo8XvhtQk7nt6JHLDHwnxRvkAddAG0ALohyOhBNJ5gptPwFmZ7O5gtF0vlyvV2uHuOhiNs27htm24DAMAkAAAqYIM8C3HIGASvAuCfICYikuy7giHiFBErhzr1l6+IAEQAGJUFQZFXH0fa-ISRF1q65G8CstHwfR-YUExtQiMRR6GPiF5kexNBkSYlHUWRN4dFBkAUUOpBIfIfSsOhmHgNhoy4fhhH8cRrHSTRdG4AxvHMS6pFiRxZkWXxkACaOQE5qJ4mSZAJmebZUKyYSQA) Shows the initial solution that only supports shapes and requires `as const`.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQ0gQQMaoK4FsMBsHAD2ATgDwAqMuAlgCYQBCG1u9xANFOQHIQAewAHxQAvFABQULlTqNmrCMSj9gEAHa0AzrBr0mLNqWpqAZotiIU6bHgIlOxs0uRrqWAtUJq0mHPiLEwpJQAPw6svoKZPBIED42-iRQAD5cvAKcLm4eXvF+doESUgBcUGoQAG6KANzi4qCQUFnuwJ7e1vkBFDJ68mycPCrCYsGUunIG5irqWuG9k2SO5jFWvrYBDqbmzTnta4mFwWE9E1GkK3Ed6-ZNri1teddKqYMCQSVllTV1-GAkwFBUPhNNoTpFDJRLBABjtWl5hABvOpSMAYABGNFQUE0wA8WJxCGIwAAFABKUpgvqKUjlKocT50xHBKTECDADDENSfADuc1Ohlpik4gsCZNqUgAvrVgqiMdQsdzqMA4BcKOkhMS1AgsBBSq9gOSLLFHgdSMrqJoBuqmVJbVBlcRCLzyryAKLER3EYkAcnIAHkACJ+qAASSwYFwEB1agBiuVFwAdN7SeKoBLkVBZZioHG4LC2mqhprtbq0ipDfncldTebLWW3lAkXapA6nTyoO7PT7-UHQ+HI9HY0q83ddkmU8F0zL0dnc37iGxiZooXqLgBtAC6nAQo7haj1lbUm8NtcbzPtcEdzogbo9JG7geDYYjUfUQ+V87Y49T6anAHo-ygAAFBAQQgbQGmgVA4AgVAAGtjAAcwTcRKQWYIEwJIkyQw3MLmJAAiC4AEYCKgUDAS8HFSVw4d8KIqEACYyIo1AqINWjlUPH1D2I71yO0Ni1Gozi4E-RRiTXBjYlIzhpMgZitygKTeIIjcaPEACoAAMQQFgIPAKCYPgpCULQqIMKwkkaKkBM8KhQjtMIQgWME9ibKgOy6IcgiGEJVzKOEjjbNzbjvV4-jWPc0TxK9KS-OIAi5KclylJU3c2lkqACMPRTSSAA) Brings the animations into the class and is still using `as const`.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQ0gQQMaoK4FsMBsHAD2ATgDwAqMuAlgCYQBCG1u9xANFOQHIQAewAHxQAvFABQULlTqNmrCMSj9gEAHa0AzrBr0mLNqWpqAZotiIU6bHgIlOxs0uRrqWAtUJq0mHPiLEwpJQAPw6svoKZPBIED42-iRQAD5cvAKcLm4eXvF+doESUgBcUGoQAG6KANzi4qCQUFnuwJ7e1vkBFDJ68mycPCrCYsGUunIG5irqWuG9k2SO5jFWvrYBDqbmzTnta4mFwWE9E1GkK3Ed6-ZNri1teddKqYMCQSVllTV1-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) Removes the need for `as const` and provides an almost finished solution.

Comment: It is a great answer! Just checked everything in my project, got the type check and even an autocompletion for the shapes and animations the user specified before - everything I dreamt of, thanks.

Although, `return this` is not compatible with the return type, TypeScript complains about this. Thinking about this edge case now...

Comment: As a pragmatic approach, we can use `return this as unknown as TrackShapes<this, TNext>` (or we can use `as any` or `@ts-ignore`). This is okay when we know more than the compiler knows and when the cast is hidden behind a good abstraction. Out of academic interest, though, I do wonder whether there is a better approach that can avoid casting. One approach that I considered was to use a wrapper class that performed the type accumulation; that had a runtime impact on memory use, though, so I decided not to use it. Let me know if you want to see it, and if you do, I might add another answer.

Comment: No, that's fine. You already did more than needed. I left a comment with TODO and added `@ts-expect-error` directive near `return this`. So at least, if something changes in compiler, I will get an error that, well, I'm not getting error anymore. Or, maybe, someday I'll get back to this issue and try to workaround it somehow. Thanks!